# Why does angular project fail AoT build when injecting Interfaces?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, interface, angular2-aot

Ok, sorry if the title was not clear.

I'm trying to implement a pattern involving injecting interfaces. It works perfectly in JIT but not in AoT. I was hoping to get an explanation of why this doesn't work and hopefully some suggestions to make it work. Here's a simplified example of the pattern.

### data-manager.interface.ts

```
@Injectable() export class DataManager implements DataManager {}

export interface DataManager {

    getData(): Promise<Array>;
    ...
}
```

^Declares Interface

### dashboard.service.ts

```
@Injectable() export class DashboardService {

    constructor(public dataManager: DataManager, ... ){
        ...
    }
}
```

^Injects Interface

### app.service.ts

```
import { DataManager as DashboardDataManager } from '.../data-manager.interface';
@Injectable() export class AppService implements DashboardDataManager {

    getData(): Promise<Array>{
        ...
    }
}
```

^Implements Interface

### app.modules.ts

```
import { DataManager as DashboardDataManager } from '.../data-manager.interface';
@NgModule({
    ...,
    providers: [

         AppService,
         { provide: DashboardDataManager, useExisting: AppService },
         ...
    ]
})
```

^Provides Interface

This pattern tricks the compiler (the JIT compiler at least) into allowing a DataManager to be injected. But why does it work for JIT and not AOT?

Here is the error that I am getting from the compiler:

```
ERROR in Can't resolve all parameters for DashboardService in dashboard.service.ts: (?, [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]).
```

*note that the compiler prints out the full path but I edited it out and only left the file name.

Please help! I would really appreciate a clean solution to this!

Thanks,
Ethan

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Very good question thank you for asking! I'll update the original post with the error message

Comment: @VitaliiChmovzh I've edited the question does that help you?

Comment: It seems some of the parameters for DashboardService constructor are not provided in app.module.

Comment: Yes that is correct. You can see from the error message that it is the first parameter that is not being provided, the first parameter is the DataManager. Very weird, remember that it works properly with JIT

Comment: I have the same problem with you. Did you solve this? @EthanMelamed

Comment: @SetoElkahfi nope I never got this to work. I was able to use class inheritance for my solution so I just did that istead. I actually found class inheritance very useful because you can have base logic in the base class and call it with super.myFunc() from the subclass’s function of the same name. If you need multiple inheritance though you are pretty much out of luck as far as I know

Comment: @EthanMelamed it's strange. For me, it happened the opposite. Previously, I used interface and inherit my service from base abstract class, and it didn't work with AOT. I removed the inherit from abstract class part, and it works perfectly.