# How to alternate service class implementation on-the-fly in component based provider?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-providers

I'm still new in Angular. Currently, I have two implementation of REST service based on one abstract class in one of our component. Just like this [scenario](https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2018/01/23/inject-alternate-service-class-in-angular/), the only difference is that I inject the service in component level:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'this-is-tag',
  template: htmlStr,
  providers: [{ provide: RESTToken, useClass: FirstRESTService }],
  ...
```

Question is, can I switch the implementation on the runtime, based on specific config? Or, should I use different approach for this problem?

EDIT:

Seems like I need to use interface, instead of abstract class here. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42698697/1137814)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up using interface, instead of abstract class for this solution. And also, the inheritance method fails when I tried to use base class for two of my services, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47163715/1137814).

This is my working solution, both in JIT and AOT compilation:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'invoice-list',
  templateUrl: './invoice-list.component.html',
  providers: [{ provide: RESTToken, useClass: InvoiceRESTService }],
  ...
```

The service that is actually being used in the component:

```
@Injectable()
export class InvoiceRESTService {

    public invoiceType: InvoiceType;

    constructor(
        private _visma: VismaRESTService,
        private _fortnox: FortnoxRESTService
    ) {}

    public get instance(): RESTServiceInterface {

        if (this.invoiceType === InvoiceType.Visma) {
            return this._visma;
        } else if (this.invoiceType === InvoiceType.Fortnox) {
            return this._fortnox;
        } else {
            console.log('Please set the invoice type.');
        }
    }

}
```

The interface itself:

```
export interface RESTServiceInterface {

  getExportDataFunctionURL(): string;

  // So far, only for Visma
  getAuthUrl?(): string;

  getButtonTitlle(): string;

  synchData(instanceUid: string, code?: string): Observable<Object>;

  updateInvoice(payload: any): Observable<Object>;

  // Loading messages
  getWaitingMessage(): string;

  getSuccessMessage(): string;

  getErrorMessage(code: VismaErrorCode | FortnoxErrorCode | BKErrorCode): string;

}
```

The services that implement the interface:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class FortnoxRESTService implements RESTServiceInterface {
   ...
   ...
   ...
}


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class VismaRESTService implements RESTServiceInterface {
   ...
   ...
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is useFactory instead of UseClass, change your code like the below example :
At first, create a factory class with a decision to DI logic:

```
export function myFactory() {
  if(myRule){
       return new FirstRESTService();
    }
  return new  SecondRESTService();
}
```

Then change your component code  to :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'this-is-tag',
  template: htmlStr,
  providers: [{ provide: RESTToken, useFactory: myFactory}],
```

Sometimes there will be a situation, you want to add some dependencies to the factory because you need it to decide whether to return serviceA or serviceB.
To satisfy this we can use deps property like this:

```
export function myFactory(obj:MyDependencyClass) {
  if(obj.HasMyRule){
       return new FirstRESTService();
    }
  return new  SecondRESTService();
}
```

also,in your component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'this-is-tag',
  template: htmlStr,
  providers: [{ provide: RESTToken, useFactory: myFactory}],
  deps: [MyDependencyClass]
```

but don't forget to include MyDependencyClass in app.module.ts.

Comment: To be honest, I prefer the interface solution compare to this factory way. Do you have pros and cos for these two solutions?